# How to export a selected value of a select tag in HTML

Tags: javascript, html, excel

I have a small HTML form with three tables. Each table has select tags. My goal is to export the HTML tables into an excel file and have the selected value ONLY to be exported. Each table should have their own tab in the excel file.

My only issue is with the selected value. When I export it to an excel file all the option values are exported and I would like ONLY the selected value to be exported.

Here is my code:

```
        <!-- 1 -->
        <table id="table1">
          <p>Table 1</p><hr>
          <tr><td>Question 1:</td>
          <td><select>
            <option value="0">0</option>
            <option value="1">1</option>
          </select></td></tr>
          <tr><td>Question 2:</td>
          <td><select>
            <option value="0">0</option>
            <option value="1">1</option>
          </select></td></tr>
        </table>

        <!-- 2 -->
        <p>Table 2</p><hr>
        <table id="table2">
          <tr><td>Question 3:</td>
          <td><select>
            <option value="0">0</option>
            <option value="1">1</option>
          </select></td></tr>
          <tr><td>Question 4:</td>
          <td><select>
            <option value="0">0</option>
            <option value="1">1</option>
          </select></td></tr>
        </table>

        <!-- 3 -->
        <p>Table 3</p><hr>
        <table id="table3">
          <tr><td>Question 5:</td>
          <td><select>
            <option value="0">0</option>
            <option value="1">1</option>
          </select></td></tr>
          <tr><td>Question 6:</td>
          <td><select>
            <option value="0">0</option>
            <option value="1">1</option>
          </select></td></tr>
        </table>
        <button  onclick="tablesToExcel(['table1','table2','table3'], ['Summary','SectionA', 'SectionB'], 'TestBook.xls', 'Excel')">Export to Excel</button>
        <script>
          var tablesToExcel = (function() {
          var uri = 'data:application/vnd.ms-excel;base64,'
          , tmplWorkbookXML = '<?xml version="1.0"?><?mso-application progid="Excel.Sheet"?><Workbook xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet" xmlns:ss="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet">'
            + '<DocumentProperties xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office"><Author>Axel Richter</Author><Created>{created}</Created></DocumentProperties>'
            + '<Styles>'
            + '<Style ss:ID="Currency"><NumberFormat ss:Format="Currency"></NumberFormat></Style>'
            + '<Style ss:ID="Date"><NumberFormat ss:Format="Medium Date"></NumberFormat></Style>'
            + '</Styles>'
            + '{worksheets}</Workbook>'
          , tmplWorksheetXML = '<Worksheet ss:Name="{nameWS}"><Table>{rows}</Table></Worksheet>'
          , tmplCellXML = '<Cell{attributeStyleID}{attributeFormula}><Data ss:Type="{nameType}">{data}</Data></Cell>'
          , base64 = function(s) { return window.btoa(unescape(encodeURIComponent(s))) }
          , format = function(s, c) { return s.replace(/{(\w+)}/g, function(m, p) { return c[p]; }) }
          return function(tables, wsnames, wbname, appname) {

            var ctx = "";
            var workbookXML = "";
            var worksheetsXML = "";
            var rowsXML = "";

            for (var i = 0; i < tables.length; i++) {
              if (!tables[i].nodeType) tables[i] = document.getElementById(tables[i]);
              for (var j = 0; j < tables[i].rows.length; j++) {
                rowsXML += '<Row>'
                for (var k = 0; k < tables[i].rows[j].cells.length; k++) {
                  var dataType = tables[i].rows[j].cells[k].getAttribute("data-type");
                  var dataStyle = tables[i].rows[j].cells[k].getAttribute("data-style");
                  var dataValue = tables[i].rows[j].cells[k].getAttribute("data-value");
                  dataValue = (dataValue)?dataValue:tables[i].rows[j].cells[k].innerHTML;
                  var dataFormula = tables[i].rows[j].cells[k].getAttribute("data-formula");
                  dataFormula = (dataFormula)?dataFormula:(appname=='Calc' && dataType=='DateTime')?dataValue:null;
                  ctx = {  attributeStyleID: (dataStyle=='Currency' || dataStyle=='Date')?' ss:StyleID="'+dataStyle+'"':''
                         , nameType: (dataType=='Number' || dataType=='DateTime' || dataType=='Boolean' || dataType=='Error')?dataType:'String'
                         , data: (dataFormula)?'':dataValue
                         , attributeFormula: (dataFormula)?' ss:Formula="'+dataFormula+'"':''
                        };
                  rowsXML += format(tmplCellXML, ctx);
                }
                rowsXML += '</Row>'
              }
              ctx = {rows: rowsXML, nameWS: wsnames[i] || 'Sheet' + i};
              worksheetsXML += format(tmplWorksheetXML, ctx);
              rowsXML = "";
            }

            ctx = {created: (new Date()).getTime(), worksheets: worksheetsXML};
            workbookXML = format(tmplWorkbookXML, ctx);

        console.log(workbookXML);

            var link = document.createElement("A");
            link.href = uri + base64(workbookXML);
            link.download = wbname || 'Workbook.xls';
            link.target = '_blank';
            document.body.appendChild(link);
            link.click();
            document.body.removeChild(link);
          }
          var rows = document.querySelectorAll("table tr");
        })();
        </script>
```

Comment: could you submit something like a JSFiddle? https://jsfiddle.net/

Answer (score 0):

The issue you're having looks to be due to the fact that: `tables[i].rows[j].cells[k].innerHTML` is the entire contents of the cell, which is the whole select element (where k = 1) not just the selected value.

The selected value of an HTML Select element can be obtained via `e.options[e.selectedIndex].value` where `e` is your select element.

In general, one can extract the first select element `e` from a parent element `parent` using `parent.getElementsByTagName('select')[0]` or by assigning an `Id` to each select, and using `document.getElementById('YourAssignedId')`, although of course you will need to handle the case where there are no select elements in the cell, as is the case when k = 0.

Comment: Thank you, I understand what to do. I am still having issues trying to accomplish this. Would you be able to modify the code so I can see where to implement this. Thank you

Comment: Something along these lines. . . 
`var select = tables[i].rows[j].cells[k].getElementsByTagName("select")[0];      
                  dataValue = (dataValue)?dataValue: (select ? select.options[select.selectedIndex].value : tables[i].rows[j].cells[k].innerHTML);`